# Swift editActionsForRowAt vs trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt TableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift4

I'm still pretty new to swift, but was wondering what the difference between `editActionsForRowAt` and `trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt` were for a `UITableView`. From my reading/research when trying to implement a swipe to delete people have used either of them.

Is there an advantage to using one over the other? Is editActionsForRowAt just more general? Or is there some sort of performance advantage?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](https://hackernoon.com/uitableview-leading-trailing-swipe-actions-in-ios-11-18cb1f267f8a) article should give you an appropriate clarification. Basically,

> trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt

overrides

> editActionsForRowAt

The former one was introduced in iOS 8.0 whereas the latter one was introduced in iOS 11.0